# Core-plot, label length

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I've a little problem on my graph when using core-plot.
I plot my datas using 2 arrays, 1 for Y axe and 1 for X axe, classic.
My problem is that I have values like this:

Values Array : (
    "0.105814",
    "0.105828",
    "0.1058",
    "0.105814",
    "0.1058",
    "0.105793",
    "0.105779",
    "0.10575",
    "0.10575",
    "0.10558"

And when I display the graph, I just see that:
[image: screenshot]

And I don't want one "0,1" but the entire value. I didn't find the parameter so if someone know, I guess it's not really complicated.

Thanks for any help!

PS: And I know it's not "label" like labels are used in core-plot but I don't know how to call it :P
And sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each axis has a property called `labelFormatter`. This is a standard `NSNumberFormatter`. You can create a new formatter that formats the labels any way you want. See [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Comment: finally found
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:4];
    [formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];
axisSet.yAxis.labelFormatter = formatter;

Comment: It would be cool to modify some of the core-plot examples to use more realistic value ranges, e.g. one graph demonstrating how to display axis labels with 4-6 digit values would be awesome!